# Limiting a query to the rows created today (Linq-to-Entities, Datetime)

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

So I've got this query:

```
var query = from r in context.Cars
            let h = context.CarHistories
                           .Where(u => r.ID == u.CarID)
                           .Where(u => u.EventID == intEventID)
                           .OrderByDescending(u => u.CreatedDate)
                           .FirstOrDefault()
            select new RefundListItem()
            {
                ID = r.ID,
                VendorID = r.VendorID,
                RecipientName = r.RecipientName,
                MostRecentSubmittedName = h.CreatedName,
                CreatedDate = h.CreatedDate,
            };
```

Later on, I add this to the query because I only want the rows that were created today:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
query.Where(u => Convert.ToDateTime(u.CreatedDate) >= today);
```

For some reason, this where statement does not affect the query at all. The query still returns items created from previous days instead of limiting them to just the rows created today.

I have also tried this but it does not work either:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today.Date;
query.Where(u => Convert.ToDateTime(u.CreatedDate.Date) >= today.Date);
```

I'm using Linq-to-Entities (MVC 4, EF 4).

Answer (score 3):

`Where` does not modify `query` instance, it returns new one with additional condition added. Assign it back to `query` to make it work:

```
query = query.Where(u => Convert.ToDateTime(u.CreatedDate.Date) >= today.Date);
```